# SQL Server Updating getting id from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to update some rows in a table, but I need to get the referring id from another table. The table structure is similar to below:

```
CoInvDept
+--------------+--------+--------+
| coinvdeptid  | coinv  | code   |
+--------------+--------+--------+

Coinv
+--------------+-------------+
| coinv        | itemnumber  | 
+--------------+-------------+
```

I need to update the code, but I have the itemnumber. I am using SQL SERVER 2008.
So far

```
UPDATE coinvdept 
SET code = 'ABC123'
WHERE (SELECT coinvid WHERE itemnumber = '12345678')
```

Comment: What is the question? Does your SQL not work? In what way? Edit: nm. I reread it is saw what wouldn't be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
UPDATE coinvdept 
SET code = 'ABC123'
WHERE coinv IN (SELECT coinvid FROM coinv WHERE itemnumber = '12345678')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE coinvdept 
SET code = 'ABC123'
WHERE coinv  = (SELECT coinvid FROM coinv WHERE itemnumber = '12345678')
```

OR

```
UPDATE T1

SET code='ABC123'

FROM coinvdept as T1
INNER JOIN Coinv as T2 ON T1.coinv=T2.coinv

AND T2.itemnumber='12345678'
```

Both should work :)

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `in` operator to match the value against the subquery result, and you need a `from` clause in the subquery:

```
update
  coinvdept 
set
  code = 'ABC123'
where
  coinv in (select coinv from coinv where itemnumber = '12345678')
```

You can also use a join:

```
update
  d
set
  code = 'ABC123'
from
  coinvdept d
  inner join coinv c on c.coinv = d.coinv
where
  c.itemnumber = '12345678'
```

Note: I have used the field name `coinv` in the queries rather than `coinvid` you used in your query, as that is what you specified in the table structures.